# Is there a way to verify encoded jwt signature using NodeJS

Tags: java, node.js, jwt

I have a working java code that can verify my JWT signature and return the claims.

Example code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
  byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(sampleKey);
  PublicKey regionalKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedKey));
  try{
    Jwt<JwsHeader, Claims> decodedTokenClaims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(regionalKey).parseClaimsJws(sampleToken);
    System.out.print(true);
  }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.print(false);
  }
}
```

I am unable to achieve the same results using NodeJS.

Could someone please help me translate the code! Thanks in advance.

Tried using Crypto but could not achieve the X509 encoding and the Public KeyObject generation.

Comment: What jwt library are you using in node.js? I haven't seen a library without a `.verify()` function.

Comment: Hi @Matt I have tried using jsonwebtoken in NodeJS.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

jwt.verify(ffaToken, STePCert, { algorithms: ['RS512'] }, function(err, user) {
    console.error(err) 
});

Tried something like this, but it keeps throwing the error "Signature Mismatch" though the same is working when run using the java code.

Comment: oh i see, probably in the creation of the pub key rather than jwt. Can you include the code for the js attempt?